How to Restrict Third-Party Keyboards in an Android App for Security Reasons?
I am particularly worried about the potential security risks associated with third-party keyboards, like the LokiBoard Keyboard, which can potentially save keystrokes entered into an EditText and compromise user data.
I want to ensure that users cannot use third-party keyboards while interacting with sensitive parts of my app. How can I restrict or block third-party keyboards to prevent them from capturing sensitive input data?
1.Is it possible to restrict or disable third-party keyboards for specific activities or views in an Android application?
2.Are there any best practices or APIs available to prevent third-party keyboards from capturing input in sensitive areas?
3.Can you suggest any other strategies or security measures to protect user input from potential keylogging by third-party keyboards?

What is the precise technical definition of a "third-party keyboard"? What do you plan to do about assistive technologies that might meet your definition of "third-party keyboard"?

Some customized android versions do have a "secure keyboard" option so it always uses their stock one when entering passwords. But that's nothing you can control or should worry about.

Do banking apps typically use custom keyboards to mitigate the risk of keystroke logging by third-party keyboards?

The code below works for most of the devices. It has not yet been tested with different phone manufacturers. Reference link reference link
public boolean isUsingCustomInputMethod() {
            InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) ctx.getSystemService(
                    Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
            List<InputMethodInfo> mInputMethodProperties =
    imm.getEnabledInputMethodList();
            final int N = mInputMethodProperties.size();
            for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
                InputMethodInfo imi = mInputMethodProperties.get(i);
                if (imi.getId().equals(
                        Settings.Secure.getString(ctx.getContentResolver(),
                                Settings.Secure.DEFAULT_INPUT_METHOD))) {
                    if ((imi.getServiceInfo().applicationInfo.flags &
                            ApplicationInfo.FLAG_SYSTEM) == 0) {
                        return true;
                    }
                }
            }
            return false;
        }


Thank you so much @DAC84 i will try this code.

Ok, a few things here:
There is no such thing as a 3rd party keyboard, because there is no such things as a first party keyboard.  There is no "default Android keyboard".  There is a keyboard app that Google wrote called latinIME that is frequently bundled with Android, but its no different than any other keyboard app.  And not all phones have that.  In particular phones for regions without latin keyboards frequently don't ship it.
Since there is no such thing as a 1st or 3rd party keyboard, there's no way to prevent someone using any keyboard they want to use, unless you're talking about hardware you own and can control what's installed on it.  If the user wishes to download a keyboard app, you cannot prevent it, cannot know that they did it, and there is no API to find out what keyboard is being used.
My suggestion is not to worry about it.  While a keyboard is a great way to install a keylogger, it's also not the only way and very few people download alternate keyboards.  I'd be more worried about random malware from the play store than I would about the keyboard.

Our security team has reviewed my app and identified a potential risk related to keystroke logging by certain keyboard apps, specifically mentioning the Loki keyboard. They are concerned that such keyboards could potentially save keystrokes entered into an EditText and compromise user data. i am attaching screenshot of issue .https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Ezyda3aeBZC6eJMeMaVdIR3fxaDECWa4/view?usp=sharing, https://drive.google.com/file/d/1NcbXx8rgX60-fgYVbA3r8fZiLJypMSVQ/view?usp=sharing

Your security team is right that that's a risk of using a keyboard app-  the keyboard has access to anything you type.  There's just nothing you can do about it to prevent them, or way to detect what keyboard is being used.  There's not even a way that whatever keyboard the OEM preinstalls (which doesn't need to be Google's and frequently isn't) doesn't have the same issue.

Do banking apps typically use custom keyboards to mitigate the risk of keystroke logging by third-party keyboards?

@PriyaKushwah The only app I've ever seen use a dedicated custom keyboard are video games.  Definitely not any banking app I use.  They mostly don't worry about it-  after all, if the user has a keylogger that's the user's fault, and there are ways to keylog that happen at the OS level without the keyboard app involved.
